# c# using system.drawing, changing colors

Tags: c#, drawing

I have a program that, when I click on the green square, turns into blue and back. i need to make the clear button, so when i press clear it should color back into green,
here is my code:

```
    {
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Gray);
        SolidBrush bgBrush=new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
        SolidBrush pixelBrush=new SolidBrush(Color.Aqua);
        Int32 rectWidth=80;
        byte[,] BitMap= new byte[8,8];

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for(int i=0;i<8;++i)
                for(int j=0;j<8;++j)
                    BitMap[i,j]=0;
        }
        private void MainFormPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics gdev=e.Graphics;
            SolidBrush currentBrush;
            for(int i=0;i<8;++i)
                for(int j=0;j<8;++j)
                {
                    currentBrush = bgBrush;
                    if (BitMap[i,j]==1)
                    {
                        currentBrush = pixelBrush;
                    }
                    gdev.FillRectangle(currentBrush, i*rectWidth,  j* rectWidth, rectWidth, rectWidth);
                    gdev.DrawRectangle(myPen, i*rectWidth,  j* rectWidth, rectWidth, rectWidth);
                }

        }
        void MainFormClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        void MainFormMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var local = new Point(e.X ,e.Y);
            SolidBrush currentBrush=bgBrush;
            Graphics gdev=Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle);
            int i=e.X/rectWidth,j=e.Y/rectWidth;
            if(i>7||j>7)
                return;
            if(BitMap[j,i]==0)
            {
                BitMap[j,i]=1;
                currentBrush=pixelBrush;
            }
            else
            {
                BitMap[j,i]=0;
                currentBrush=bgBrush;
            }
            gdev.FillRectangle(currentBrush, i*rectWidth,  j* rectWidth, rectWidth, rectWidth);
            gdev.DrawRectangle(myPen, i*rectWidth,  j* rectWidth, rectWidth, rectWidth);
            GetHexCode();
        }
        void GetHexCode()
        {
            UInt64 res=0,marker=1;
            for(int i=0;i<8;++i)
                for(int j=0;j<8;++j)
                {
                  res+=BitMap[i,j]*marker;
                  if(i==7&&j==7)
                    break;
                  marker*=2;
                }
            hexFild.Text=res.ToString("X16");
        }
        void SaveButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog MyFileDlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            MyFileDlg.DefaultExt = ".fw";
            MyFileDlg.Filter = "fw data file (*.fw) *.fw|";
            if (MyFileDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
              MessageBox.Show(MyFileDlg.FileName+" "+hexFild.Text);
              StreamWriter fwStream=new StreamWriter(MyFileDlg.FileName);
              fwStream.Write(hexFild.Text);
              fwStream.Close();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Invalidate();
        }
```

Can i get some ideas how can i do it? Thanks.

Note: I'm new into drawing stuff :)

[image: My form]

Here is my little form that i made.

Comment: The simplest thing would be to reset all the values to zero in your Bitmap array like you do in your constructor  (which, btw is unnecessary as the values will all be zero to start) or just set it to a new array, and then trigger the repaint/invalidate

Comment: can you give me an example? because i tried to make an "for" for bitmap to draw like in "MainFormPaint" but i need  "PaintEventArgs" for this. I have to use "EventArgs" because i want to clear everything when i press the button

Comment: Just make your button click event, in its entirety:`BitMap = new byte[8,8]; this.Invalidate();`